# Show that the subspace A is the whole Hilbert space H

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

"Let $A$ be a subset in a Hilbert space $H$, such that $x\in H$ and $x \perp A$ imply $x = 0$.

(1) Show that the closed subspace that is generated by $A$ is $H$.

(2) Let $f(x)$ be a square summable function on $\Bbb R$, such that its Fourier transform is almost everywhere (strictly) positive. Let $B$ be the set of all functions of the form $f(x+a)$, with $a\in R$
arbitrary. Show that the closed subspace generated by $B$ is the whole $L^2(\Bbb R)$."

(1) feels trivial but I am not sure how to formulate, maybe something like this: since x ⊥ A => x = 0 which says that the only vector ⊥ to A in H is the null vector => ... => every vector i H can be described with vectors in A.. something.. something..

When trying to do (2) I got a hint: apply the
above result (1) to the set A given by the Fourier transform of set B.

Sincerely Ingvar

Comment: (1) Note that $A^\perp=(\mbox{Span }A)^\perp= (\overline{\mbox{Span }A})^\perp$. Also $(F^\perp)^\perp=\overline{F}$ for every subspace $F$. And finally $\{0\}^\perp=H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1., one can use the projection on the closure of the subspace generated by $A$.

For 2., we can use result of 1.. Let $f$ be a square integrable function whose Fourier transform is almost everywhere positive. Let $g\in L^2$ be orthogonal to $f(\cdot +a)=:\tau_a(f)$ for all real number $a$. Then using Plancherel's formula, we get 
$$\int_{\Bbb R}\widehat f(x)\widehat{\tau_ag}(x)dx=0.$$
Since $\widehat{\tau_ag}(x)=e^{iax}\widehat g(x)$, we get that for each $a$, 
$$\int_{\Bbb R}\widehat f(x)\widehat{g}(x)e^{iax}dx=0,$$
hence the Fourier transform of the integrable function $\widehat f\widehat g$ vanishes everywhere. This proves that $\widehat f\widehat g=0$ and the assumption on the Fourier transform of $f$ gives $\widehat g=0$. Conclude.